# Video courses for learning C++

Tags: c++

Do you have any recommendations on great video courses as a complement to books for learning C++?

Comment: what's wrong with books?

Comment: Yes they are great but I will correct as a complement.

Comment: You can find C++ courses here from many providers: https://coorsy.com/topics/c-plus-plus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have not used these and I'm not sure about international shipping, but these are partly taught by [Yashavant Kanetkar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yashavant_Kanetkar).

- **[Quest C++ Programming](http://quest.ksetindia.com/product_info.php/Product/Quest_C++_Programming)**

Don't let the 550 price throw you, it's in Rupees so about $13 US.

--

Update for [shipping](http://quest.ksetindia.com/shipping.php):

> For shipments to USA/Canada, UK,
>   Europe, Japan, Australia, we charge
>   INR 2000 (USD 40) for a single order
>   of 1 to 16 Quest Courses.

Comment: Ok but there is a download as well right?

Comment: @Chris_45, looks like it, http://quest.ksetindia.com/download_quest_products.php

Comment: Yes seems like good stuff, thanks! BTW do you know anything more about Kanektkar , is he engaging and comfortable to listen to and so?

Comment: I haven't watched any videos with him so I'm not sure, but I thought he was great at explaining things in one of his books so it's likely he brings that to the videos too.

Comment: -1: The Kanetkar books are really bad, so these videos might be best avoided too.

Answer (score 2):

[ShowMeDo](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/C++) It's a nice place to start seeing for C++ and more.

Answer (score 2):

[Wrath Lands](http://www.rdxgames.net/projects/wrathlands/index.html) is a project about creating a text based RPG in C++.  It's not really something you'd want to learn C++ for the first time with, but it is basically a guy starting from scratch and creating a game, dictating and trying to explain what and why he's doing it while also dealing with errors.

I found it to be entertaining at the least with some good pieces of information.  Definitely not a standard though.

Answer (score 2):

The Stanford CS deparment has several courses that you can watch (free) online. Of iterest to you may the [Programming Paradigms](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=2d712634-2bf1-4b55-9a3a-ca9d470755ee) lectures, which cover an intro to C++ among other topics.

MIT also appears to have a similar [course](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-088January--IAP--2010/CourseHome/index.htm) available.

Comment: The Stanford lectures are awesome.

Comment: They don't actually teach c++ though.  They make use of Stanford-made libraries instead the STL to hide potentially confusing syntax from students.

Comment: @Kat C++ != STL, though clearly a professional C++ developer should know the STL (and Boost, and ...).

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/bb496952.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: The second link seems broken and points now to C# Tutorials on MSDN. Perhaps the correct link should be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733747%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Nothing beats [stanford course](http://see.stanford.edu/player/SEEslplayer.aspx?coll=11f4f422-5670-4b4c-889c-008262e09e4e&co=175420f7-f467-42e4-adf1-29ebdb24e199&sl=true) Its quite comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com)

They offer 5 C++ courses as of today, and for 29 bucks you can watch them all within a month.

It is based on Windows/Visual Studio, but the knowledge is applicable in all other platforms. The courses also include the last features of the language.