# C videos anywhere online

Tags: c++, c

Does anyone have any knowledge of C or c++ tutorials that teach the language on video and through examples?

Comment: You've tagged this C and C++. A tutorial on C is mainly syntactic and talks a lot about pointers and structures. A tutorial on C++ probably assumes you know this much and will likely focus on object oriented programming and the STL. Which type of tutorial do you want? I'm guessing C, since that's how you titled the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2746593/10396; http://stackoverflow.com/q/1935438/10396

Comment: This should not be down rated since others have been give 5 ups for similar questions....

Comment: We don't allow these types of questions anymore.  If you see any similar questions, please flag them for closure.

Comment: Lots of online C / C++ courses here, first hour is free for all of them and a good part of the content is video: https://learninglineapp.com/schedule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FredOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252000/fredoverflow) did [start such a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168958/videos-and-podcasts-by-c-celebrities) (you need enough rep to see deleted questions to see this one) for C++ a while ago, which via some detours ended up on the [C++ chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)['s wiki](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com): http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/videos-and-podcasts-by-c-celebrities